# Trying out a $t$-test using R

Tags: r, logistic

I would like to:

i) check if the odds ratios (OR) for each factor level are significantly different.

**Edited**:

This is the model I used:

```
NewMod2C <- glm(formula = surv ~ as.factor(season) + as.factor(pgrp) + as.factor(sline)
                                                   + as.factor(tb5) 
                                                   + as.factor(gest3) + as.factor(int3)
                                                   + as.factor(agit) 
                                                   + as.factor(teat2),
                                                   family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                                                   data = lesna)
summary(NewMod2C)

confint(NewMod2C)

data.frame(exp(NewMod2C$coefficients))

                   exp.NewMod2C.coefficients.
(Intercept)                         6.5599000
as.factor(season)2                  0.7203071
as.factor(pgrp)2                    1.3495993
as.factor(pgrp)3                    1.0388424
as.factor(pgrp)4                    1.1013092
as.factor(sline)2                   1.2668896
as.factor(tb5)2                     0.8663428
as.factor(tb5)3                     0.7307868
as.factor(tb5)4                     0.6555165
as.factor(tb5)5                     0.5770979
as.factor(gest3)2                   1.3520849
as.factor(gest3)3                   2.6598991
as.factor(int3)2                    0.8146875
as.factor(int3)3                    0.2941530
as.factor(agit)2                    0.6305899
as.factor(agit)3                    0.7208870
as.factor(teat2)2                   1.3266645
as.factor(teat2)3                   1.5567743
```

Are there any ways of determining if, for example, the levels of `pgrp` are significantly different?

```
    as.factor(pgrp)2                    1.3495993 a
    as.factor(pgrp)3                    1.0388424 b
    as.factor(pgrp)4                    1.1013092 c
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered `drop1(NewMod2C,test="Chisq")` ?

Comment: @Joran, with all due respect to our contributors at stackexchange, its very hard to get any response from the site. I am not sure whether my questions are not attractive enough or not many people are covering the questions at this site. That is why I prefer to have my questions here because I am sure that I will get answers to my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Placing confidence intervals around odds ratios is generally done by assuming the coefficients are normally distributed around the estimate with a standard error of the estimate being a typical returned value from the glm call.

At any event the information you have offered will be insufficient to generate any sort of inference. Perhaps you can get more information with:

```
summary(NewMod2C)$coefficients
```

Comment: I just added the model used; and you are right, I also need to state the standard errors. Your help is really needed!

Comment: Adding the model without the data or the output of what I offered is not going to provide even enough information to produce confidence intervals, .... much less the contrasts you are asking for. Given the relatively small differences in those odds ratios, it is doubtful that you will find any significance difference.